# Custom link component inline spacing

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm creating a component library based on lit web components. However, i suspect my problem to be unrelated to Lit itself but rather related to shadow dom.

My link component has the following styles and only renders an anchor tag inside:

```
// link.component.scss
:host {
  display: contents;
}

.my-link {
  display: inline;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

// link.component.ts
override render() {
    return html`
        <a class="my-link"><slot></slot></a>
    `
}
```

When i try to use the link within text i get some spaces added where no space should be (at least the spaces are not there for the HTML standard anchor tag):

```
<div style="display: block;">
    A sentence that ends with a <my-link>link</my-link>.
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
    A sentence that ends with a <a href='/'>link</a>.
</div>
```

which results in the following outcome:
[image]

I played around with the code and different "display" properties but i need my link to be "display: inline" as it should break and flow with the text.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The issue you have is the usage of `div` which by default are block-level element and will break to a new line as such. inline elements neither can have a height nor a width with the exception of images as those are treated like inline-block elements.

Comment: The div is only a wrapper element in this example. The link is display: inline.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please post a [repro] that shows the issue here.

Comment: This may be due to newline characters in component template.

Comment: @fen1x that was actually it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the spacing within the render() method. Fixed by using:

```
override render() {
    return html`<a class="my-link"><slot></slot></a>`
}
```

Thanks to fen1x or the comment :)